# iOS Swift How to check Key Availability in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, swift3, nsmutablearray

I am having some set of NSMutableArray like:

```
(
        {
        name = "ILTB";
        source = "iltb.net";
    },
        {
        name = "Baran Bench";
        source = "baranbench.com";
    },
        {
        name = "Income Tax India 1";
        source = "Income Tax India 1";
    }
)
```

How to check Key availability in this NSMutableArray. For Example I need to check "ILTB" is already in my MutableArray or not.

Comment: "ILTB" is the value here not a key ..please make it clear what you what....

Comment: @Dhiru I need to check if "ILTB" is already in my MutableArray or not

Comment: Do the Searching in array , this is already answered below @KavinKumarArumugam

That will work for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> First of all `ILTB` is not key but its value for key `name`.

You probably want search from array. Now in Swift instead of `NSArray` use Swift's native array of dictionary and then use `first(where:)` this way.

```
let array = [[String:String]]()
if let res = array.first(where: { $0["name"] == "ILTB" }) {
    print(res)
}
```