# Get element from array of dictionaries according to key

Tags: swift

I have array like `[[:String:Any]]`

I have a `value` string , and i want to extract the element with that key **without looping** (one line).

To check if its there I used this :

```
 if(array.map{$0["NAME"] as! String}.contains(value)){
```

Is there a way to also **extract** this dictionary **within** this `if` statement ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For that no need to `map` the array. You can use `contains(where:)`

```
if array.contains(where: { $0["name"] as? String == value }) {
    print("Exist")
}
```

If you want object(dictionary) from array also than you can use `first(where:)`

```
if let dict = array.first(where: { $0["name"] as? String == value }) {
    print(dict)
}
```

For more on `first(where:)` check this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43446612/ios-swift-how-to-check-key-availability-in-nsmutablearray/)

Comment: My friend Nirav :) not sure I get you, i need to get the dictionary inside this if statment

Comment: @Curnelious Welcome mate, if you want object(dictionary) from that array you can use `first(where:)`  like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/43446750/6433023

Comment: @Hamish Suggested that also